# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in LinksController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Hi guys i'm new to Ruby trying to build a website and this happens.

I'm really comfused why this isn't working. I've been here reading other peoples threads not really found a good solution.

```
unknown attribute 'user_id' for Link.

Rails.root: c:/sites/rubbit

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:18:in `new'
Request
```

I think the problem started after I changed from Links.new to           current_user.links.build

LinksController

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :show]

  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  # GET /links/1
  # GET /links/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /links/new
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

  # GET /links/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /links
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /links/1
  # PATCH/PUT /links/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /links/1
  # DELETE /links/1.json
  def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
    end
end
```

Model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :links
end
```

Model Link

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I really don't have a clue if I need to include more.

EDIT

DB/Migrate files...

I might be missing some but when i "rake db:migrate" nothing happens..

2 files

```
_create_links
    class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :links do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.string :url

          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

AND

_devise_create_users

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateLinks` needs a line:

```
t.references :user
```

Comment: Still not working same error ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in LinksController#new

Comment: After adding this line `bundle exec rake db:migrate:redo` or `bundle exec rake db:drop:all db:create:all db:migrate`.  You should be able to verify that there is a `user_id` column on the links table.

Comment: I see we drop the database and recreate it from the ground because I added user. But if u got time or know where i can find the answer why can't I just add :user to the current migration?

Comment: @carversmind The migration system is in place to allow you to change your production and staging databases over time.  When you run the migrations, a row is inserted into the `schema_versions` table with the timestamp matching your migration.  Once this row is there, Rails won't re-run that database-- it assumes no changes have been made.  In development, you can use commands like those I referenced above.